# Acumatica Excel Query SSO

Tags: acumatica

Using SAML login for SSO and looking for a way to make the /export and /odata paths function.  Currently we get a Windows Auth prompt for username and password which works for non-Claims (Native) users, but we have no method to get the SSO users access.

Is there a method to get the system to use the login page for these credentials rather than the windows security prompt or some other method to allow this to work / provide this basic capability?

Thanks

Comment: I asked Acumatica about that recently and was told that it is not supported right now... you have to use basic authentication (username/password).